# Kendo UI - Grid questions

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am evaluating Kendo UI for use of it in our project. I would be using the Kendo UI JS (not the ASP.Net MVC one).

I stumbled upon a couple of things Kendo grid does not support. I just want clarification on some of the functionalities (some of the questions may sound very basic. Sorry I am just evaluating on the basis of demos provided and trying to fit in our requirement). I do not require any code but just require your help in evaluating kendo UI

1. Kendo Grid does not support Grouping of Headers ?

   > |-----------Header Master------------------|
   >
   > |--Sub Header-------|-----Sub Header----|
2. Kendo Grid does not support Frozen Columns ?
3. Does Kendo Grid support multiple summary columns with custom aggregate(that would be pulled from data source and hence not calculated on client side) ? How can we achieve this ? By Customer Footer template ?
4. I could not find any example on the website, which shows how kendo ui grid deals with large data. say 10,000 rows ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers to the questions at the current moment (28/10/2013):

1. Kendo Grid does not support grouped Headers ( you can search the
   forums for some feasible work-arounds)
2. Kendo Grid does not
   supported frozen-columns, [however it should be implemented for the
   future releases.](http://feedback.kendoui.com/forums/127393-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/2436512-grid-frozen-columns)
3. What is supported as footer templates is
   demonstrated [here](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/aggregates.html).
4. What do you mean by larget data? If  you
   enable server paging only the records for a specific page will be
   send to the client, so you can use it with as many records as you
   want. Also check [virtualization](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/virtualization-remote-data.html) (please notice it still works
   the same as a paging mechanism, so you can use it again the same way
   as in a regular paging scenario)